# client&admin react-scripts: not found

Tags: reactjs, docker, api-platform.com

I'm trying to install api-platform with the docker images. The problem is that the containers will not start, exiting with code 127.

```
$ react-scripts start
/bin/sh: react-scripts: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
```

I'm using Docker for windows with Linux containers. I tried everything I could think of. The only thing I found in support was rebuilding the client and the admin but to no avail. Anybody an idea?

I use the provided Docker files from the api-plaform: https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform.

Dockerfile admin:
    # https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#stop-at-a-specific-build-stage
    # https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#target

```
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact
ARG NODE_VERSION=13
ARG NGINX_VERSION=1.17


# "development" stage
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine AS api_platform_admin_development

WORKDIR /usr/src/admin

# prevent the reinstallation of node modules at every changes in the source code
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN set -eux; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp \
        g++ \
        make \
        python \
    ; \
    yarn install; \
    apk del .gyp

COPY . ./

VOLUME /usr/src/admin/node_modules

ENV HTTPS true

CMD ["yarn", "start"]

# "build" stage
# depends on the "development" stage above
FROM api_platform_admin_development AS api_platform_admin_build

ARG REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT

RUN set -eux; \
    yarn build

# "nginx" stage
# depends on the "build" stage above
FROM nginx:${NGINX_VERSION}-alpine AS api_platform_admin_nginx

COPY docker/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

WORKDIR /usr/src/admin/build

COPY --from=api_platform_admin_build /usr/src/admin/build ./
```

Dockerfile: client
    # https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#stop-at-a-specific-build-stage
    # https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#target

```
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact
ARG NODE_VERSION=13
ARG NGINX_VERSION=1.17


# "development" stage
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine AS api_platform_client_development

WORKDIR /usr/src/client

RUN yarn global add @api-platform/client-generator

# prevent the reinstallation of node modules at every changes in the source code
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN set -eux; \
    yarn install

COPY . ./

VOLUME /usr/src/client/node_modules

ENV HTTPS true

CMD ["yarn", "start"]


# "build" stage
# depends on the "development" stage above
FROM api_platform_client_development AS api_platform_client_build

ARG REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT

RUN set -eux; \
    yarn build


# "nginx" stage
# depends on the "build" stage above
FROM nginx:${NGINX_VERSION}-alpine AS api_platform_client_nginx

COPY docker/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

WORKDIR /usr/src/client/build

COPY --from=api_platform_client_build /usr/src/client/build ./
```

Comment: Can you provide your Dockerfile ?

Comment: I've updated my post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved it by directly typing `yarn install` in both directory (`/client` and `/admin`). You can then start `docker` images (`docker-compose up -d`).

Hope it helps.